# How can I print days of a month with moment php?

Tags: php, object, foreach, var-dump

I am working with [moment.php](https://github.com/fightbulc/moment.php/blob/feature/te/i18n/README.md). I want to print all days of for example the month april 2018:

```
$weekdayNumbers = [
    1,2,3,4,5,6,7
];

$m = new \Moment\Moment();
$dates = $m->getMomentsByWeekdays($weekdayNumbers, 3);

echo "<pre>";                    
var_dump($dates);
echo "</pre>"; 

 foreach($dates as $key=>$value){
  $date = $value->date;
     echo $date."<br>";
}
```

There are dates printed, but when I remove from the code the following line:

```
    echo "<pre>";                    
    var_dump($dates);
    echo "</pre>";
```

...then my page is empty. Nothing is printed. How can this be possible?

var_dump output is:

```
array(18) {
  [0]=>
  object(Moment\Moment)#4 (6) {
    ["rawDateTimeString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "now"
    ["timezoneString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
    ["immutableMode":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-03-29 11:07:28.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(Moment\Moment)#5 (6) {
    ["rawDateTimeString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "now"
    ["timezoneString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
    ["immutableMode":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-03-30 11:07:28.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
  }
  [2]=>
  object(Moment\Moment)#7 (6) {
    ["rawDateTimeString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "now"
    ["timezoneString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
    ["immutableMode":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-03-31 11:07:28.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
  }
  [3]=>
  object(Moment\Moment)#8 (6) {
    ["rawDateTimeString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "now"
    ["timezoneString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
    ["immutableMode":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-04-01 11:07:28.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
  }
  [4]=>
  object(Moment\Moment)#9 (6) {
    ["rawDateTimeString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "now"
    ["timezoneString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
    ["immutableMode":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-04-02 11:07:28.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
  }
  [5]=>
  object(Moment\Moment)#10 (6) {
    ["rawDateTimeString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "now"
    ["timezoneString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
    ["immutableMode":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-04-03 11:07:28.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
  }
  [6]=>
  object(Moment\Moment)#11 (6) {
    ["rawDateTimeString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "now"
    ["timezoneString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
    ["immutableMode":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-04-04 11:07:28.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
  }
  [7]=>
  object(Moment\Moment)#12 (6) {
    ["rawDateTimeString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "now"
    ["timezoneString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
    ["immutableMode":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-04-05 11:07:28.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
  }
  [8]=>
  object(Moment\Moment)#13 (6) {
    ["rawDateTimeString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "now"
    ["timezoneString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
    ["immutableMode":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-04-06 11:07:28.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
  }
  [9]=>
  object(Moment\Moment)#14 (6) {
    ["rawDateTimeString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "now"
    ["timezoneString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
    ["immutableMode":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-04-07 11:07:28.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
  }
  [10]=>
  object(Moment\Moment)#15 (6) {
    ["rawDateTimeString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "now"
    ["timezoneString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
    ["immutableMode":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-04-08 11:07:28.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
  }
  [11]=>
  object(Moment\Moment)#16 (6) {
    ["rawDateTimeString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "now"
    ["timezoneString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
    ["immutableMode":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-04-09 11:07:28.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
  }
  [12]=>
  object(Moment\Moment)#17 (6) {
    ["rawDateTimeString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "now"
    ["timezoneString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
    ["immutableMode":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-04-10 11:07:28.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
  }
  [13]=>
  object(Moment\Moment)#18 (6) {
    ["rawDateTimeString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "now"
    ["timezoneString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
    ["immutableMode":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-04-11 11:07:28.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
  }
  [14]=>
  object(Moment\Moment)#19 (6) {
    ["rawDateTimeString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "now"
    ["timezoneString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
    ["immutableMode":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-04-12 11:07:28.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
  }
  [15]=>
  object(Moment\Moment)#20 (6) {
    ["rawDateTimeString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "now"
    ["timezoneString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
    ["immutableMode":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-04-13 11:07:28.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
  }
  [16]=>
  object(Moment\Moment)#21 (6) {
    ["rawDateTimeString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "now"
    ["timezoneString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
    ["immutableMode":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-04-14 11:07:28.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
  }
  [17]=>
  object(Moment\Moment)#22 (6) {
    ["rawDateTimeString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "now"
    ["timezoneString":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
    ["immutableMode":"Moment\Moment":private]=>
    bool(false)
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-04-15 11:07:28.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
  }
}
```

Comment: whats the output of `var_dump($dates)`?

Comment: @Jeff I updated the output in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `date` is not accessible from the object directly, but after a `var_dump()` (see [PHP DateTime DateInterval isset changes after var_dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45871847/php-datetime-dateinterval-isset-changes-after-var-dump)).

The object `Moment` extends [`DateTime`](https://php.net/datetime) class, so you could use the [`format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method:

```
foreach($dates as $key=>$value){
   $date = $value->format("Y-m-d");
   echo $date."<br>";
}
```

Comment: @Jarla I've updated the answer to explain why it work when you have a `var_dump()` but not when you're not using it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see in the description of the moment.php you get an array of `moment objects` from `getMomentsByWeekdays`. So I think the correct way would be

```
$value->getDay()
```

instead of

```
$value->date;
```

Comment: Yes, this is working without the var_dump, but it is printing only 29
30
31
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
13
14
15

Comment: I would need something like 2018-04-02